# Join conditions without primary key on multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1  -

```
Yr  | Qtr  | T1_Data
2012    Q1   100
2012    Q2   400
```

Table 2 -

```
Yr  | Qtr  | T2_Data
2012    Q1   200
2012    Q2   500
```

Table 3 -

```
Yr  | Qtr  | T3_Data
2012    Q1   300
2012    Q2   600
```

Output Table

```
 Yr   | Qtr | T1_Data | T2_Data | T3_Data
 2012   Q1     100      200       300
 2012   Q2     400      500       600
```

I am trying to achieve the above join condition. I tried using left outer join by referring to some articles and came with a query. But I don’t help.

```
    select 
        t1.yr,
        t1.qtr,
        t1.t1_data,
        t2.t2_data,
        t3.t3_data
    from 
        table1 t1 
    inner join 
        table2 t2 on (t1.yr  = t2.yr and t1.qtr = t2.qtr) 
    inner join  
        table3 t3 on (t2.yr  = t3.yr and t2.qtr = t3.qtr)
```

Comment: What is the result of the query?

Comment: That query *looks* perfectly fine, what happens when you run it?

Comment: You need to remove the comma after `t3.t3_data`. If you do that you'll get your expected results. Note, however, that `2012 Q1` and `2012 Q2` will need to exist in all three tables for you to get your results. Also, will you have just one row per year/quarter in each table? If there will be multiples then you'll need to `SUM` the values. Just say so if that's the case - it can be done.

Comment: @mattytommo, I am expecting only 2 rows. But I get more than 10 rows when I run that query

Comment: Ed is right.  See answer below that uses the PIVOT and SUMS for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PIVOT.  Run this script, it should give you what you're looking for.  Obviously you would want to replace my dummy statements with your actual tables. (I revised to match your data and table structure given.)

```
 SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q1' AS 'Qtr',      
            100 AS 'Val'
            INTO #tempTable1
    UNION
    SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q2' AS 'Qtr',
            400 AS 'Val'

    SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q1' AS 'Qtr',
            200 AS 'Val'
            INTO #tempTable2
    UNION
    SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q2' AS 'Qtr',
            500 AS 'Val'

    SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q1' AS 'Qtr',      
            300 AS 'Val'
            INTO #tempTable3
    UNION
    SELECT 
            2012 AS 'Yr',
            'Q2' AS 'Qtr',
            600 AS 'Val'


    SELECT Yr, Qtr, [Table1] AS T1_Data, [Table2] AS T2_Data, [Table3] AS T3_Data
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, 'Table1' AS 'TableID' FROM #tempTable1
        UNION
        SELECT *, 'Table2' AS 'TableID' FROM #tempTable2
        UNION
        SELECT *, 'Table3' AS 'TableID' FROM #tempTable3
    ) p
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM (Val)
    FOR TableID IN
    ( [Table1], [Table2], [Table3] )
    ) AS pvt
    ORDER BY pvt.Yr;


    DROP TABLE #tempTable1
    DROP TABLE #tempTable2
    DROP TABLE #tempTable3
```